# How can I access set of MaterialState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create ElevatedButton that uses SvgPicture for displaying icon inside of it. I have defined foregroundColor inside ButtonStyle to resolve color in accordance with current MaterialStates. However, this foregroundColor is being applied only to Text and Icon widgets. How can I resolve this color the same way for my SvgPicture widget? Or atleast have an access to set of MaterialState of my ElevatedButton?

I tried to research the way Flutter stores set of MaterialState for ElevatedButton, but still haven't found out it yet. Also, I came across MaterialStateMixin and as I understand  its purpose is solely dedicated to create custom buttons in Flutter with the help of GestureDetector, InkWell, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `MaterialStatesController` which exposes the widget's material states `Set<MaterialState>`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStatesController-class.html

```dart
class _SvgButtonState extends State<SvgButton> {
  late final _statesController = MaterialStatesController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _statesController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
      label: const Text('Button'),
      statesController: _statesController,
      style: ...,
      icon: ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: _statesController,
        builder: (context, value, child) { // value is Set<MaterialState>
          return SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/...',
            colorFilter: value.contains(...) ? ... : ...,
          );
        },
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

To access the set of MaterialState in Flutter, you can use the MaterialStateColor class. However, it's important to note that SvgPicture may not automatically respond to changes in MaterialState like Icon does. In such cases, you may need to manually manage the color changes for your SvgPicture.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // Your button's onPressed logic
  },
  style: ButtonStyle(
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
      // Resolve color based on MaterialState
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return Colors.red; // Change to the desired color
      }
      return Colors.blue; // Default color
    }),
  ),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/your_icon.svg',
        // Set the color manually based on MaterialState
        color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
            return Colors.red; // Change to the desired color
          }
          return Colors.blue; // Default color
        }),
      ),
      SizedBox(width: 8), // Adjust as needed
      Text('Button Text'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

In this example, both the foregroundColor of the ElevatedButton and the color of the SvgPicture are manually managed based on the MaterialState. Adjust the colors and conditions as needed for your specific use case. Keep in mind that SVG rendering might not fully support dynamic color changes based on MaterialState, and you may need to use alternative approaches or packages for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Great answer from ChatGPT. And yet it does not consider even basics of Flutter.  
PS: This is not working solution.